# OLAP-технологии

Tags: книги, olap, sql-server

Здравствуйте, посоветуйте пожалуйста хорошую литературу (желательно книгу) по OLAP-технологиям в MS SQL Server 2008. Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Читаю периодически [здесь](http://www.intuit.ru/department/database/mssqlsas2008/class/free/status/).